# How to create a fallback for ajax modal popup

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a modal popup on my page. Obviously if javascript is present, no issues but if it isn't, I need to deal with it.

The first issue is that I automatically show the popup from the page load event - anyone know a technique that will allow me to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to include links that take you to the non-JS versions of the popups, and hide them with CSS when you detect that JS is available.

An example of such detection is having a "noJS" class on the `<body>` element, with an *inline* script to remove that class (don't wait for `onload` or similar event). If JS is disabled, the class is left there as it is, and CSS rules for no JS are used.

Answer (score 1):

If Javascript isn't present your options are fairly limited. However to make sure you can still present the user with the relevant info you could consider using the noscript tag.

Your browser does not support JavaScript!

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

As an alternative to a popup you could consider displaying the data on the page with speficic emphasis to it being relevent before the user reads the rest of the content.

Another option would be to display the pop-up data on a seperate page.